# Prove: the function $g$ has a global minimum in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a polynomial of a even $n$ degree, such that $0\leq f(x)$
>
> let $g=f+f'+f''+\cdots+f^{(k)}$, prove $g$ has a global minimum in $\mathbb{R}$ when $k$ is the $k$-th derivative

How should I approach this?

Comment: What is $k$? Any integer?

Comment: @ClementC. edited

Comment: My question is -- $k$ can be anything (the statement is to be proven for all $k\geq 0$)?

Comment: there is no restriction on $k$

Comment: A start could be : if $f \geq 0$ for all $x$ then what can you say about coefficient of highest exponent monomial in f?

Comment: Also please try and be more careful when you write questions. It can be very off-putting for some users to answer and then have the question changed afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the coefficient of the highest-order term is positive and the degree of $g$ is even we can choose $C$ big enough such that $g(z)>f(0)$ for all $|z| > C $ . Then since $g$ is continuous and $[-C,C]$ is compact, there is $ x\in [-C,C]$ such that $f(x) \leq f(y)$ for all $y\in [-C,C]$. Then $f(x)$ is a global minimum.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I forgot to write that $g$ starts with the function itself

Comment: Seems he missed to add $f$ in the sum but edited now?

Comment: Why $g$ is even? is $g$ a sum of an even and odd functions?

Comment: g is even because f is even: the monomial with the highest power of g will be the monomial with highest power of f because the derivatives of f all have lower degrees...

Comment: @math635 So for example $x^6+x^5$ is even?

Comment: no its not. I meant that the degree of the highest power is even. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

when $f$ is polynomial, derivatives of $f$ are polynomial as well. Further $g$ is polynomial.

Because $f \gt 0$ and $f$ is even, $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x)= + \infty$. And because $f$ is the highest order polynomial among $f', f^{(2)},f^{(3)}$ etc. we can conclude $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} g(x)= + \infty$. Thus, g has global minimum.